# Using cell link function to run code (in Google Colab notebooks)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I'm looking at the "Link to cell" functionality in Google Colab. Using the three dots to the right of the cell, you can get a link specifically to the contents of that cell in that notebook to link to later in that notebook or others. Is there a way to use this functionality to run the code contained with in the linked cell?

For example, if I have two notebooks:  notebookA & notebookB.

- notebookA contains the master code for a scoring function
- notebookB is the current notebook I'm working in

Is there a way to create a cell in notebookB and use the link to the cell or cells in notebookA to run them within notebookB? *I'm looking for a way to have Colab notebooks that contain master versions of code (including functions) that I use across several other Colab notebooks, so that when I update that code in the master version each of the other notebooks has the most up-to-date version of that code without copying and pasting it over each time.*

Comment: Have you considered having the code on github and installing in the notebooks from there?

Answer (score 0):

One option you can use is this:

-Save the master code in a file mymodule.py

-Put "mymodule.py" in your google drive.

-Mount your drive using this button:

[image]

-Append path and import "mylib.py":

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('/content/gdrive/My Drive')
import mylib
```

-Now you can use a function from "mylib.py" like in any module:

```py
mylib.myfunc()
```